# How to stop keypress from being typed in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, pynput

I am working on a program that remaps the computer keyboard for me because I type on an alternative keyboard layout. However, I was able to send a different keystroke when one key was pressed, but I was not able to stop the original keystroke from also being registered as input. I am using Python and any help would be appreciated.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, KeyCode, Listener, Controller

# Your functions

keyboard = Controller()

def function_a():
    keyboard.type('a')

def function_b():
    keyboard.type('b')

def function_c():
    keyboard.type('c')

def function_d():
    keyboard.type('e')

# Create a mapping of keys to function (use frozenset as sets are not hashable - so they can't be used as keys)
combination_to_function = {
    frozenset([KeyCode(char='a')]): function_a,
    frozenset([KeyCode(char='b')]): function_b,
    frozenset([KeyCode(char='c')]): function_c,
    frozenset([KeyCode(char='d')]): function_d,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='e')]): function_e,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='f')]): function_f,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='g')]): function_g,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='h')]): function_h,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='i')]): function_i,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='j')]): function_j,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='k')]): function_k,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='l')]): function_l,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='m')]): function_m,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='n')]): function_n,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='o')]): function_o,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='p')]): function_p,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='q')]): function_q,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='r')]): function_r,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='s')]): function_s,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='t')]): function_t,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='u')]): function_u,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='v')]): function_v,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='w')]): function_w,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='x')]): function_x,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='y')]): function_y,
##    frozenset([KeyCode(char='z')]): function_z,
}

# Currently pressed keys
current_keys = set()

def on_press(key):
    # When a key is pressed, add it to the set we are keeping track of and check if this set is in the dictionary
    current_keys.add(key)
    if frozenset(current_keys) in combination_to_function:
        # If the current set of keys are in the mapping, execute the function
        combination_to_function[frozenset(current_keys)]()

def on_release(key):
    # When a key is released, remove it from the set of keys we are keeping track of
    current_keys.remove(key)

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: You can't do this in the application layer. You'd have to claim exclusive control of the keyboard and consume all of its input. That sounds impossible to do without OS support.

Comment: what OS do you use ? There should be better method to do this but it may depend on OS.

Comment: Raspbian @furas. Right now I am just deleting the key that I typed, and then sending the new key. However, I am still wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Linux uses text files "keymaps" to define keyboard layouts - and you can edit them  in text editor to create own layout.